# How to do subtract column if lot no and item name and percent is same in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two View one for issue and other for Receive.
issue View Output

```
Lot No  Operation            Item    Wt       %      Fine Wt
2112001 Lot Addition Create 2 Sadak 180.00  91.94    165.49
2112001 Lot Addition Issue  2 Sadak  30.00  91.94     27.58
2112001 Lot Addition Issue  2 Sadak 300.00  99.50    298.50
2201002 Lot Addition Create 3 Hiway 100.00  91.80     91.80
2201002 Lot Addition Issue  3 Hiway   2.00  91.94      1.84
2201003 Lot Addition Create 4 Saran  19.00  91.40     17.37
2201003 Lot Addition Issue  4 Saran  15.00  91.94     13.79
```

Receive View Output

```
Lot No  Operation               Item       Wt       %      Fine Wt
2112001 Lot Addition Receive    2 Sadak  52.00   91.94     47.81
```

Output View

```
Lot No  Operation             Item       Wt      %     Fine Wt
2112001 Lot Addition Create 2 Sadak     158   91.94    145.27
2112001 Lot Addition Issue  2 Sadak     300   99.50    298.50
2201002 Lot Addition Create 3 Hiway     100   91.80    91.80
2201002 Lot Addition Issue  3 Hiway      2    91.94     1.84
2201003 Lot Addition Create 4 Sarangi   19    91.40    17.37
2201003 Lot Addition Issue  4 Sarangi   15    91.94    13.79
```

if Lot no, Item Name and percent is same from 2 view than issuewt. and receivewt. should be minus for that lot no. Kindly i suggest me select query what I have done is union and subtract.  Suggest  front end approach will be better or front end vb.net will be better. copy in two different data table and output will be to third data table.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

If the columns and data types are the same, then you can use `UNION ALL` to combine the data from the 2 views.
Then aggregate the combined results.

Query for MS Sql Server :

```
SELECT 
  [Lot No]
, MIN([Operation]) AS [Operation]
, [Item]
, SUM([Wt]) AS [Wt] 
, [%]
, SUM([Fine Wt]) AS [Fine Wt]
FROM
(
    SELECT [Lot No], [Operation], [Item], [Wt], [%], [Fine Wt]
    FROM [Issue View Output] 
    
    UNION ALL

    SELECT [Lot No], [Operation], [Item], -[Wt], [%], -[Fine Wt]
    FROM [Receive View Output] 
) q
GROUP BY [Lot No], [Item], [%]
ORDER BY [Lot No], [Item], [%];
```

Comment: HI LukStorms Thanks a lot you save my day. Yes type and columns are same. Your query work perfectly as per my requirement.

Comment: Cool. Well, for clarity.  The column names don't actually have to match 100%. A union query will simply use the names or aliases of the query that's on top.